# Simple database structure to link subjects and exam boards

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I'm new to Sql and want to use sqlite to create a database to store data about which topics are needed by which exam boards.

So far I've created two tables - one called `board` and one called `topic`. I'm not sure how I should represent the relationship between boards and topics. I have read a bit about Normal Form, and I'm pretty sure that I shouldn't be putting multiple entries into one field, and also that having fields like `topic1`, `topic2` etc. is not the way to go.

My sql so far is below. Could someone please help me with the next step - how to make this database actually work for my requirements while not breaking every rule in the book?

For example, I'd like to be able to quickly find out which boards require knowledge of set theory or reciprocal functions etc.

Thanks in advance.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "topic" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "topic_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "level" INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "board" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "board_name"    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "link_to_syllabus"  TEXT
);
INSERT INTO "topic" ("id","topic_name","level") VALUES (1,'Pythagoras'' Theorem','F');
INSERT INTO "topic" ("id","topic_name","level") VALUES (2,'Circle theorems','H');
INSERT INTO "topic" ("id","topic_name","level") VALUES (3,'',NULL);
INSERT INTO "board" ("id","board_name","link_to_syllabus") VALUES (0,'Edexcel','https://qualifications.pearson.com/en/qualifications/edexcel-gcses/mathematics-2015.html');
INSERT INTO "board" ("id","board_name","link_to_syllabus") VALUES (1,'OCR','https://www.ocr.org.uk/qualifications/gcse/mathematics-j560-from-2015/');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, a board can have one or more topic, and a topic can be in one or more boards. If it is correct, you are searching for a many to many relationship, wich is obtained with the table:

```
CREATE TABLE board_topic (
    board_id   INTEGER  NOT NULL
                          REFERENCES topic (id),
    topic_id INTEGER  NOT NULL
                          REFERENCES board (id),
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (
        board_id   ,
        topic_id 
    )
)
```

About the query you asked for, after you insert some data into the association table just showed, the query looks like:

```
SELECT board.id, board_name FROM board 
JOIN board_topic ON board.id = board_topic.board_id 
JOIN topic ON topic.id = board_topic.topic_id 
WHERE topic_name = "Circle theorems";
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Could you maybe explain how the joins work in the query? Just from a really basic view point, could the two `JOIN` statements be indented to show that they together constitute some subset or modification of `board` referred to in the first line?

Comment: Yes, you properly said that they could be indented by concept.
You can imagine that you are creating a new table, in wich the rows are a subset of the board table rows, but these rows contains also the joined columns from the topic table.